# making a simple math quiz with switch statement for loop and while loop in java

Tags: java

so my problem is that in my code I need it to ask 5 questions and then ask the user if he/she wants to continue or stop. If they choose to continue it should take them back to the menu(switch statement) and they can choose to do another set of math problems. for each option in the switch statement it should only have 5 math questions. If they choose stop the code should count how many questions it got right and calculate the percantage correct. Any tips or what is wrong with my code.. I know I am missing my for loop because I'm not quiet sure where to put it and how to make the code work with it in.

```
{
    //keyboard reader
    Scanner in = new Scanner((System.in));
    //3 number variables
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int answer;
    int operator;
    int question = 0;
    int num3;
    double questionCount = 0;
    double correct = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 7)
    {
        num1 = (int)(1+Math.random()*10);
        num2 = (int)(1+Math.random()*10);
        num3 = (int)(1+Math.random()*100);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Wsu School of Math! ");

        System.out.println("please choose one of the following options for your math Quiz: ");
        System.out.println("1: Addition with number 1-10");
        System.out.println("2: Additon with numbers 1-100");
        System.out.println("3: Subtraction with numbers 1-10");
        System.out.println("4: Subtraction with numbers 1-100");
        System.out.println("5: Multipication with numbers 1-10");
        System.out.println("6: Exit the Quiz");
        operator = in.nextInt();
        switch (operator)
        {
            case 1: System.out.println(num1+"+"+num2+"=");
                question = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case 2: System.out.println(num1+"+"+num3+"=");
                question = num1 + num3;
                break;
            case 3: System.out.println(num1+"-"+num2+"=");
                if(num1 < num2)
                {
                    int temp = num1;
                    num1 = num2;
                    num2 = temp;
                }
                question = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case 4: System.out.println(num3+"-"+num1+"=");
                if(num1 > num3)
                {
                    int temp = num1;
                    num1 = num3;
                    num3 = temp;
                }
                question = num1 - num3;
                break;
            case 5: System.out.println(num1+"*"+num2+"=");
                question = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case 6:
                if(operator == 6)
                {
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
                break;
        }
        answer = Integer.parseInt(in.next());

        if(answer == -99)
        {
            System.out.print("good bye!\n");
        }
        else if (answer == question)
        {
            System.out.print("Correct!\n");
            questionCount++;
            correct++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("incorrect.\n");
            System.out.println("the correct answer is = "+question );
            questionCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Amount of problems attempted: "+questionCount);
    System.out.println("Amount of problems Correct: "+ correct);
    System.out.println("Percent you got on the test = "+correct/questionCount*100);
}
```

Comment: first of all, welcome to stack overflow.. please tell us *what exactly* doesn't work. most people wont be willing to just plug your code into their IDE to see what's going on

Comment: @neuron what my problem is, is that When it runs. it pops up the menu like it should and then if the user enters '1' it does the first case and then goes back to the menu. I need it to do the 1st case 5 times and then stop and calculate the amount correct. and then if the user wants to do more it can or stop and finish the program.

Comment: I provided you with a detailed answer. Have a look at it

Answer (score 4):

Try to write your "case 6" like this:

```
case 6:
        System.out.println("Amount of problems attempted: "+questionCount);
        System.out.println("Amount of problems Correct: "+ correct);
        System.out.println("Percent you got on the test = "+correct/questionCount*100); 

        System.exit(-1);
        break;
```

I cut the "System.out.print ..." from where they were and put them inside your "case 6:". But the System.exit(-1); will close the application. If you want to simply exit the while loop you would need a boolean to inter the loop and you would change its value inside "case 6" like this:

```
boolean a = true;
while(a){
    //...
   case 6:
       //...
       a = false;
       break;
   //...

}
```

or you can just make sure that your (i<7) become false. It depends on what you want to achieve. Hope this help!!!

Comment: @Progamminnoob didn't I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows:

```
              case 6:
                  // DEL Start
                  //if(operator == 6)
                  //{
                  //    System.exit(-1);
                  //}
                  // DEL End

              break;


          }
          boolean isEnd = false;
          if (operator != 6) {  // Add
              answer = Integer.parseInt(in.next());
              // Add Start
              if (answer == question)
              {
                  System.out.print("Correct!\n");
                  questionCount++;
                  correct++;
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.print("incorrect.\n");
                  System.out.println("the correct answer is = "+question );
                  questionCount++;
              }
              // Add End
          // Add Start
          }
          //
          else {
              //answer = -99;
              isEnd = true;
          }
          // Add End
          //if(answer == -99)
          if (isEnd)
          {
              System.out.print("good bye!\n");
              break;  // Add
          }
          // DEL Start
          //else if (answer == question)
          //{
          //    System.out.print("Correct!\n");
          //    questionCount++;
          //    correct++;
          //}
          //else
          //{
          //    System.out.print("incorrect.\n");
          //    System.out.println("the correct answer is = "+question );
          //    questionCount++;
          //}
          // DEL End
        }
        System.out.println("Amount of problems attempted: "+questionCount);
        System.out.println("Amount of problems Correct: "+ correct);
        System.out.println("Percent you got on the test = "+correct/questionCount*100);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood, you are missing a loop. The general structure of your code should look like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int questionBlock = 0; questionBlock < 5; questionBlock++) {
    System.out.println("select question..");
    int blockIndex = sc.nextInt();
    for (int question = 0; question < 5; question++) {
        //initialize random variables
        switch (blockIndex){
            case 1:
                //do stuff
                break;
            case 2:
                //do other stuff
                break;
            default:
                //wrong input.
        }
    }
    // evaluate results of last 5 questions..
}
```

When you are reading input, you might want to do it that way:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int blockIndex = 0;
while(blockIndex < 1 || blockIndex > 5) {
    System.out.println("Please select a question block, by entering it's number..");
    String text = sc.next();
    try{
        if (text.equals("exit")) {
            //exit
        } else {
            blockIndex = Integer.parseInt(text);
            continue;
        }
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //do nothing here
    }
    System.out.println(text+" was not a valid block number. Please enter an index between 1 and 5!");
}
//rest of code
```

This will make sure your input is between 1 and 5. also it gives the user the opportunity to exit the application by entering `exit`

Comment: for my class the professor wants us to use to a while loop and a for loop.. which i don't have the for loop in there.. cause i'm not sure how to have both. so if i use your example from above what do i do for a while loop?

Comment: 8 + 12

That is the correct answer!
Please choose one of the following options for your math quiz:
1. Addition with numbers 1­10
2. Addition with numbers 1­100
3. Subtraction with numbers 1­10
4. Subtraction with numbers 1­100
5. Multiplication with numbers 1­10
6. Exit the program
6
You got 12 problems correct out of 15 problems attempted. That is 80.00 percent correct.
Goodbye! **** this is what the output is supposed to somewhat look like. Im close but not close if that makes sense haha

Comment: i added a little code snippet which uses a while loop. you can use it to read numbers from the console

Comment: okay so now I think i made progress.. but my problem is now that when i run the program and lets say i select menu option '1'. it does 5+3 or whatever and then goes straight to the menu again. When i need it to do 5+3 and have the user enter the answer.. then do 2+5 or another from that same menu option and have it repeat 5 times. which is a for loop i think. how can i implement that? @neuron